# Having hard time running ROS tutorial over my ROS2 installation

Tags: ros2

I'm new to ROS and Gazebo.
I've installed a fresh new copy of ubuntu along with ROS2_HUMBLE and Gazebo (Ubuntu Jammy 22.04, ROS 2 Humble Hawksbill, Gazebo Fortress)

Now i'm taking part of a course called "Mastering in Gazebo" by "The Construct" based on ROS Noetic. Most of the files in the tutorial have different names and path compare to the one in my ROS2 installation.

Question:

- Is it possible to downgrade from ROS2 Humble to ROS Noetic given that my OS and Gazebo is as written above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

While it is definitely possible, you should consider whether you should [downgrade to Noetic](https://wiki.ros.org/Distributions), since it is going to be EOL in 3 years.

I would personally suggest that you stick to ROS2 Humble, and try to learn the concepts. You can use Gazebo Classic with ROS2 without any *(much)* hassle, so you can follow along with the course from The Construct which would likely be in Gazebo Classic. Also, do note that there exists a package called [ros1_bridge](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge) and [ros_gz](https://github.com/gazebosim/ros_gz), which might help you interface with ROS 1 code that you may find on the course. While it would not be the main objective, by doing this you might gain useful insights in porting legacy code onto a newer codebase - which will be very appreciated in the general field of Software Engineering.

If you would still want to roll back to ROS Noetic, you have the following choices:

1. **Install ROS 1 alongside ROS 2** : If you only want to use ROS 1 for your course, and ROS 2 for everything else, this is the simplest choice. [This](https://answers.ros.org/question/350474/can-i-install-ros1-and-ros2-on-the-same-computer/) question provides insight on how to do that.
2. **Use docker images**: This is a very flexible option, however, this comes with a steep learning curve at the beginning. The benefit is that this approach would the most modular approach of the three. [This](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Run-2-nodes-in-single-or-separate-docker-containers.html) tutorial on the ROS 2 documentation provides a lot of information on how to do it.
3. **Completely remove ROS 2 and install ROS 1** : This option would make sense if you plan on continuing with ROS 1 for some time. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANWHO_-FKlU) video and [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/57213/how-i-completely-remove-all-ros-from-my-system/) forum post would help you in doing that. The idea is simply to remove all traces of ROS 2 from your computer, and then install a fresh copy of ROS 1.

All the best!